# Can not find executable path of flatpak apps

Tags: package-management, paths, flatpak, brave

App installed using `apt` package manager starts running when I type the app name in terminal like `firefox`. [Using Kubuntu 22.04]

```bash
which firefox
```

This command will show the path of `firefox` in my system.

In case of Flatpak apps, how to run the the flatpak app without

```bash
flatpak run org.mozilla.firefox
```

**So, how can I find flatpak app's path like `which firefox`.**

I need it so that I can set `brave browser` app in $CHROME_EXECUTABLE path for flutter development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`which` returns the full pathname of an executable, provided it exists in one of the directories listed in the search PATH. `flatpak` exposes executables for installed applications in `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin`. However, that directory is not automatically included in the PATH when you install `flatpak`. You could include it in the PATH yourself. Then, you could launch the Firefox version installed by flatpak with the command `org.mozilla.firefox`.

You can always launch an executable by providing the full path name:

```
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/org.mozilla.firefox
```

So you can just set the variable as:

```
CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/org.mozilla.firefox
```

> So, how can I find flatpak app's path like which firefox.

Just by being informed about how flatpak does it, or from the documentation. No tool can provide that information if the executable is not in the path or if you do not know the name of the executable.

Comment: Thanks again vanadium bro. You have helped me twice.

Comment: somehow I also got soltuion a few moment ago by randomly use `locate firefox/firefox` and it lead me to `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.mozilla.firefox/x86_64/stable/SOME_BIG_VALUE/files/lib/firefox/firefox-bin` .